# Can we use existing planet database for Nominatim

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, nominatim

i have imported data from the OSM to PGSQL using osm2pgsql for generating tiles,

and now i need to add Nominatim support also, this Nominatim requires the same OSM data. can we use the existing database? or do i need to create new one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to create a new one. Nominatim requires a different database scheme than your rendering stack because it needs to perform really different queries. Using the same database for rendering and geocoding would be very inefficient, if possible at all.

Comment: Yep, the structures are verry different if you want to do rendering or search for strings: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Databases#Database_Schemas