# Renderd "planet_osm_polygon" not exists?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, nominatim

I'm trying to create my map server. Importing a planet with osm2psql was perfect, I installed nominatim and is working too. I installed the libapache2-mod-tile packet, caring about to not create the database. After the configuration, Renderd make this error:

An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default':

> ERROR:  relation "planet_osm_polygon" does not exist

I'm sure that the database wasn't corrupted, as nominatim is working like a charm.

There is a way to recover this missing table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nominatim and Mapnik/renderd use different database schemes, so you better put them in separate databases.

See [Can we use existing planet database for Nominatim](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126349/can-we-use-existing-plant-database-for-nominatim) for more details. Unfortunately, noone has ever documented the nominatim database scheme yet.